# Window keyboard shortcut to open firefox browser options page?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

On mac it's conveniently labelled right in the menu: `cmd + ,`, is there a shortcut like this for windows? I can't find it on the official documentation.

Even the mac version isn't documented.

Comment: Options in what?

Comment: Sorry, did not realize I didn't put firefox in the title/body, only had it tagged. I've edited the title to include firefox browser

Comment: Maybe you mean Firefox settings? Am I correct..if is that would be something like Ctrl+P or Ctrl+O, or even Ctrl+.

Comment: @Tyþë-Ø That is what I meant, the settings/options/preference page, CTRL +  P and O brings up the printing and open a file window respectively, and CTRL + . does nothing for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is there a shortcut for Firefox options for windows?

<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> works for me on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 86.0:

- <kbd>alt</kbd> open the Firefox menu
- <kbd>t</kbd> selects **T**ools
- <kbd>o</kbd> selects **O**ptions

This works with the Menu Bar hidden or shown.

Comment: Thank you, this will work well even if it's not a one step shortcut like the one available on mac, as long as I get to keep my hands on the keyboard.